# GET vs POST vs SESSION in Backend App

Tags: php, security, session, post, get

Hi and thanks for your time. I´m developing an web app where my logged in customers will be able to watch video classes. Right now i´m using GET passing the information about the type of the videos through URL. For example:

User 1 have MASTER COURSE ->>>> URL = curso.php?page=master

User 2 have BASIC COURSE ->>>> URL = curso.php?page=basic

You see, i think there´s a security problem here, because if user 2 type in his URL "page=master" he will be able to watch the videos that´s not allowed for him.

So i´m writing a security check for each page, to see id that user ID can access the desired page.

But i think it´s too much useless work. If i use the method POST on my Buttons, and submit the data via POST, would it be totally security to presume that a given user wont be able to see content that´s not suitable for him ? After all, the URL will be always the same, something like curso.php.

And there´s the possibility of using Session, but can i define a Session value with a submit button or something like that ?

I know, i know, a lot of newbie questions, but that´s just my second back end system and i fill like missing a lot of security practices here.

Will appreciate any help or tips.

Thanks a lot and sorry my bad English.

Comment: this is kind of subjective question there are many thing by which you can by which you can stop user to access content in url

Comment: Use `get` so users could bookmark your page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So i'm writing a security check for each page, to see id that user ID can access the desired page.

Good. That is what you need to do. Before presenting any data to the user, check that they have permission to see it.

> But i think it´s too much useless work. If i use the method POST on my Buttons, and submit the data via POST, would it be totally security to presume that a given user wont be able to see content that´s not suitable for him ? After all, the URL will be always the same, something like curso.php.

In most browsers, it takes less than half a dozen clicks to examine the post data used to make a request. POST hides nothing from users, it just avoids waving it in their faces.

> And there's the possibility of using Session, but can i define a Session value with a submit button or something like that?

You can't define a session value client side. The data must be sent to the server in a request.

Comment: Thanks Quentin, going to keep the checking system by page until learn how to implement HTTPS and SSL.

Comment: SSL will protect the data from third parties. It won't hide it from the person sending it.

Answer (score 3):

POST is as unsecure as GET. POST can't be used to increase security. You must perform check on the server based on the user information who is currently logged in. So use GET because that is the way HTTP is designed to be used and do necessary check on server.

You need some kind of authentication to be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Just relaying on using POST is definitely not safe. You can easily start a POST Request with a REST-tool for example.

I don't know if you are using a underlying framework (I would recommend this, since you're basically asking for user right management), but if not I propably would save the rights in a User class or session and check against the given parameters.

Basically it doesn't matter if you use POST or GET. But HTTP says that you use GET if you want to retrieve data from the server and use POST if you want to send data to the server.

So use GET and write yourself a nice class where the rights of the authenticated user is stored and check if the user is able to retrieve the desired content.

Comment: It's easy also to create a simple HTML file containing `<form method="post" action="desired_page"><input type="hidden" name="page" value="master" /><input type="submit" /></form>` and you don't have to use any tools to send `post` variables, just a notepad and browser :-)

Comment: That's true, just wanted to make clear that POST is not some invisible magic.

Answer (score -3):

In any case both `Session` and `POST` would be a great improvement to your security in comparison to `GET`, that's for sure. But you still need your checks on your page though

Comment: Just because you can't see the POST data in the URL does not mean, that it magically invisble arrives at the server.

Comment: This is not a matter of HOW you send and receive data. It's a matter of server-side security checks.

Comment: I'm just saying `GET` is about the worst you can go if you want to keep users from accessing unauthorized pages. Not everyone knows how to adjust a `POST` value, whereas any user can clearly see how to modify a URL

Comment: what the hack .. request and post are as unsecure  as  get [to know difference see this](http://www.brightmeup.info/articles/6/Choosing-GET-and-POST-request-method)

Comment: That sentence doesn't even make sense. Request and post are the same as post...? However, I'll read the article, seems interesting

Comment: sorry ..its was my bad .. damn on my fingers ... and trust me they dont listen to me :)